# load applet dependency from client side

Tags: java, applet

Hi i have an applet with AllPermision , my applet has alot of dependency to jasperreport , apache commons and .... my clients have Low Bandwidth for downloding applet dependencies. in this situation i want to load jar files (dependencies) from client path. 
does anybody have a solution?

browser ie 6 

jre 1.6 update 14

Comment: Note, at the time of writing the version of the Sun/Oracle JRE with all security patches is 6u20. You don't want to be using earlier versions with untrusted stuff from the internet.

Comment: i have legacy system and i have to use this version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your jar files to JRE_HOME/lib/applet folder.

for more information see the following:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/linux/jdkfiles.html#applet